# Open SQL condition in RFC_READ_TABLE call via PyRFC

Tags: python, where-clause, opensql, pyrfc

How do I specify the Open SQL WHERE clause in an RFC_READ_TABLE query using PyRFC?

I'm trying to get started with PyRFC to have python do table extractions from SAP (in the absence of a supportive/cooperative basis team). In this example from http://scn.sap.com/community/scripting-languages/blog/2012/11/04/revisiting-python-and-sap-with-pyrfc, they use:

```
pyrfc.Connector.call("RFC_READ_TABLE", QUERY_TABLE=table, DELIMITER='|')
```

http://saplsmw.com/node/101 says that a WHERE clause needs to be passed as an OPTION to the RFC call. How do I do this in PyRFC? (OPTIONS is an exporting variable of type table in RFC_READ_TABLE's function module declaration on the SAP end).

EDIT: OK http://scn.sap.com/community/scripting-languages/blog/2014/05/05/python-for-basis has an example of sending the WHERE clause in OPTIONS:

```
OPTIONS = [{'TEXT':source_where}])
```

So it looks like the syntax is an array (maps the SAP table type) of single element dictionaries where the key is the SAP data type and the value is the WHERE clause.

So next question is: How do I specify a PACKAGE SIZE to be sent to RFC_READ_TABLE so that I can extract large tables without hitting internal table limits?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

RFC_READ_TABLE has a parameter 'ROWCOUNT' which specifies the maximum number of rows to return in a single call.

Of course, if you say restrict it to 1000 rows at a time there may be other rows that you never download if the table contains more than 1000 rows.

To solve this there is another parameter, 'ROWSKIPS' through which you specify the starting row you want to return.

So, with the first call
ROWCOUNT = 1000
ROWSKIPS = 0

The next call
ROWCOUNT = 1000
ROWSKIPS = 1000

The next call
ROWCOUNT = 1000
ROWSKIPS = 2000

and so on, incrementing ROWSKIPS each time as follows: ROWSKIPS = ROWSKIPS + ROWCOUNT.

An example PyRFC call with both ROWCOUNT and ROWSKIPS defined, which reads from TCURR in batches of 10 (and where FCURR is set to 'USD'):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from pyrfc import Connection, ABAPApplicationError, ABAPRuntimeError, LogonError, CommunicationError
from ConfigParser import ConfigParser
from pprint import PrettyPrinter

def main():

    try:

        config = ConfigParser()
        config.read('sapnwrfc.cfg')
        params_connection = config._sections['connection']
        conn = Connection(**params_connection)

        options = [{ 'TEXT': "FCURR = 'USD'"}]
        pp = PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
        ROWS_AT_A_TIME = 10 
        rowskips = 0

        while True:
            print u"----Begin of Batch---"
            result = conn.call('RFC_READ_TABLE', \
                                QUERY_TABLE = 'TCURR', \
                                OPTIONS = options, \
                                ROWSKIPS = rowskips, ROWCOUNT = ROWS_AT_A_TIME)
            pp.pprint(result['DATA'])
            rowskips += ROWS_AT_A_TIME
            if len(result['DATA']) < ROWS_AT_A_TIME:
                break

    except CommunicationError:
        print u"Could not connect to server."
        raise
    except LogonError:
        print u"Could not log in. Wrong credentials?"
        raise
    except (ABAPApplicationError, ABAPRuntimeError):
        print u"An error occurred."
        raise

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```