# How To Get only Transparent Table in SAP Table using Java Connector (JCo)

Tags: java, abap, jco, sapjco3

I'm looking for fetching only **Transparent Table** for **RFC_READ_TABLE** using **Java JCoFunction**

```
JCoFunction function2 = template2.getFunction();

JCoTable jcoTabled = function2.getTableParameterList().getTable("DATA");
```

```
Result :

/BEZ3/CHCDPAL                 
TRANSP  
----------------------------------
/BEZ3/CHCDLSP               
TRANSP  
----------------------------------
/BEZ3/CHCDPAS                
VIEW
```

Currently getting **All Tables** along with **Transparent Table** like **VIEW** too. So, is there any filter to fetch only **TRANSP** Table List.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open SQL condition in RFC\_READ\_TABLE call via PyRFC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24172130/open-sql-condition-in-rfc-read-table-call-via-pyrfc) - Ignore the fact that the question is about pyrfc, the issue you have is about RFC_READ_TABLE (-> parameter OPTIONS)

Comment: @SandraRossi, Both are Different. I wanted Transparent Table List for RFC_READ_TABLE in Java JcoFunction.

Comment: Maybe this other answer will participate to do a complete answer then: [JCo RFC_READ_TABLE Data Buffer Exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54189708/jco-rfc-read-table-data-buffer-exceeded)

Answer (score 0):

Use the parameter `OPTIONS` of `RFC_READ_TABLE` to filter rows, below is to read all lines from `DD02L` where `TABCLASS` column equals 'TRANSP' :

```
...
JCoFunctionTemplate template2 = sapRepository.getFunctionTemplate("RFC_READ_TABLE");

function2.getImportParameterList().setValue("QUERY_TABLE", "DD02L");

JCoTable filterOptions = function2.getTableParameterList().getTable("OPTIONS");
filterOptions.appendRow();
filterOptions.setValue("TEXT", "TABCLASS = 'TRANSP'");
...
```

Comment: use above filter It shows only one result and that too is not correct one.

Comment: @sandra_rossi, It's not the code Error. we need to do this way for filter of TRANSP Table.

`filterOptions.setValue("TEXT", "DD02L~TABCLASS = 'TRANSP'");`

Comment: I don't understand why your code needs the table "alias" `DD02L~`. It's optional, like in all SQL implementations, and like in all answers in Stack Overflow, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52201563/read-a-table-from-a-sap-system-using-jco). Maybe you are in a special context.